# Devise unable to get current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to get the token of the successfully logged user so I created the `get_token` method in my `Application Controller`:

```
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      if current_user.role.role_type === 'user'
        current_user.regenerate_token

        @user_token = current_user.token
        puts @user_token #logging properly

        user_profile_path
      else
        rails_admin_path
      end
    end

    def get_token
      return @user_token
    end
```

Now, I want to get the value of the token in my controller namely, `Api::V1::CommentController` so i have my code

```
class Api::V1::CommentController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
   @http_status = { :status => false }
  end


  def create
    puts get_token #I just want to log this


    render :json => @http_response
  end
end
```

With the code above, I am not getting the generated token when testing it using POSTMAN. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
I have this in my routes:

```
    namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
       devise_scope :user do
         post 'comment/create' => 'comment#create'
       end
      end
    end
```

Comment: what does `current_user.regenerate_token` do?

Comment: it just updates the existing user token with the newly generated. I'm using `has_secure_token` [built in with Rails 5](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/23/has-secure-token-to-generate-unique-random-token-in-rails-5.html)

Comment: Can you put 'byebug' or any other debugger just before `current_user.regenerate_token` and see if that method is doing something not intended?

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable you are setting will be available for only that specific request.

Just change the method to

```
def get_token
  current_user.token
end
```

Comment: it says .token is nil. I think my controller `Api::V1::CommentController` can't determine if user is logged or not. so i added code

`if user_signed_in?
   puts get_token
  else
   puts "not yet"
  end
`

Comment: It is working in views but not in inherited controllers from ApplicationController